# Decompress / Decrypt hex to string

Tags: encryption, hex, compression, reverse-engineering

I have a rather unusual question I would say...

So I have a massage in pure Hex-data format. I have no idea how it came to be, could've been encrypted or compressed or whatever....

Now, I know what the message is supposed to say. My Question: Is is somehow possible to reverse-engineer this encryption/compression algorithm?

*Note*: The hex snippets and msg. are always pretty short, **however** the hex data is always devisable by 16 (e.g. 96 Bytes, 176 Bytes, 304 Bytes, ...) no idea if that's important...

Example:

Hex: `CA83F0EDE7E6239F5E03BA2B40264917EEFD7FE14DEC4F13302840FDD2F8E1B21F2607FCC06657D5745639090D5EA2FC78D3D4A8B38A38C96574129BE654F900188892AAEF1387FA986C3A6C0E36AB2CCC8963097603117B19C4E1D723579C4D`

Solution: `Thus the onions and the apples and everything in them were colorised`

Comment: Some modes of encryption such as ECB and CBC use a block cipher that operates on 16 bytes at a time *and* require the data to be a multiple of that block size.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I thought since it's about algorithms and reverse-engineering it might be fitting.. but I understand... Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this is one of the few times that the plaintext makes as much sense to me as the ciphertext, while being a fully formed English sentence.